# Sed command filtering extra text/removing

Tags: centos

```
"GET /?add=jt1777,justine,tignor,f,November_24_1983,Skeleton_,Italy HTTP/1.1" 200 34053
```

does anyone know how to use the sed command to cut out the extra lines or filtering like

```
"GET /?=jt1777,f,November_24_1983,Skeleton_,Italy HTTP/1.1" 200 34053"
```

but include just only the name `"justine, tigor"`. Thats all I need, just the first and last name.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk`

```
echo "\"GET /?add=jt1777,justine,tignor,f,November_24_1983,Skeleton_,Italy HTTP/1.1\" 200 34053" | awk -F, '{print $2","$3}'
```

Explanation:

- `-F,` Here you're delimiting text with `,`
- `'{print $2","$3}'` You'll print the field 2 and 3 within the delimiter `,`. If you want to print the comma, since this is being used as delimiter, it won't print so you must hardcode it `","`

Comment: Okay thanks understood!!! God Blessed you brother thank you

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like "cutting just" fields 2 and 3 could apply:

```
echo ..... | cut -d, -f2,3
```